# Does my code using Node.js and callback function works same as Java Threads?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I am new to Node concurrency model.

The code below shows creating java threads and starting it concurrently.

```
package com.main;

class MyThread implements Runnable{

  private int num = 0;

  MyThread(int num){
    this.num = num;
  }

  public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        System.out.println("Thread "+this.num);
        for(int c = 0; c < 5; c++){
            System.out.println(" Running thread "+(c+1));
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}

public class Example01 {

/**
 * @param args
 */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Thread[] ts = null;
    try{
        ts = new Thread[]{
            new Thread(new MyThread(1)),
            new Thread(new MyThread(2)),
            new Thread(new MyThread(3))
        };

        for(int x = 0; x < ts.length; x++){
            ts[x].start();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

}
```

From above code you can see, I am starting 3 threads and each thread print   5 times, sleeping 2 sec's in between.

The output of above code is

```
Thread 1
Thread 2
Running thread 1
Thread 3
Running thread 1
Running thread 1
Running thread 2
Running thread 2
Running thread 2
Running thread 3
Running thread 3
Running thread 3
Running thread 4
Running thread 4
Running thread 4
Running thread 5
Running thread 5
Running thread 5
```

In a same way I have written a javaScript code and run by Node which is as follows

```
function forEach(theArray,func){

  if(Array.isArray(theArray) === true){
    for(var x = 0; x < theArray.length; x++){
        func(theArray[x],x);
    }
  }
}


forEach([1,2,3],function(num,index){

  console.log("Thread "+num);

  forEach([0,1,2,3,4],function(num,index){
    setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("Running Thread "+(num+1));
    },2000);
  });

});
```

The above code's output is as follows,

```
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 3
Running Thread 1
Running Thread 2
Running Thread 3
Running Thread 4
Running Thread 5
Running Thread 1
Running Thread 2
Running Thread 3
Running Thread 4
Running Thread 5
Running Thread 1
Running Thread 2
Running Thread 3
Running Thread 4
Running Thread 5
```

Does the above two code's (javascript and java) run in the same way ?

Is my understanding of Java's thread equivalent to javascript's callback is correct ?

Please explain me if I am wrong.

Comment: No.  There are no Javascript threads (other than webWorkers in a browser, but that isn't what is in play here).  So, Java threads are pretty much nothing like Javascript callbacks.  They are completely different things.  User Javascript in node.js is ***single threaded***.  Only one piece of Javascript runs at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q:** Does my code using Node.js and callback function works same as Java Threads? 
**A:** Short answer. **No**.

Despite the `print output` you got for both Java and NodeJS really do make the latter look like it is multi-threaded.

Unfortunately NodeJS is programmed using Javascript, a single threaded language and this can be evidently observed from the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) JS documentation. That is, you will not see any keyword relating to `threads`.

***However do note that it is possible for you to spawn child processes in NodeJS.***

See:
https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

**Q:** You might then ask. So why am I seeing this thread-like phenomenon in my NodeJS application?
**A:** For running application code - NodeJS has only **one thread** and it has a **queue** (think LinkedList) that keeps track of events (code blocks).

When you start your application.

Node will parse every single line of code from top to bottom, similar to how your Java application runs. When it sees `setTimeout` operation, Node will `push` that block of code (function) for the `setTimeout` operation into the event queue and tag it as (Hey, execute this block of code in **minimum** of 2 seconds time)

Again. **Note** Node does not guarantee your code to be ran in exact 2 seconds, it only guarantees you that it will be executed in minimum of 2 seconds. E.g. If the main thread is blocked (infinite loop or something), you will find that the code block for the `setTimeout` operation will never get executed.

So, moving on. Hence after the `setTimeout` code block gets pushed into the event queue. The main thread moves on and parse the Javascript code line by line until it is done. Once its done, the next on queue's code block gets `shifted` and the event queue begins processing again.

And this goes on and on. When there is nothing in the event queue then the main thread does nothing until something comes into the queue.

Hope this clarify your doubt on why your NodeJS application is running like it has multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is inherently single-threaded. There is one main event loop that will process all kinds of events and callbacks one after the other.

Threads in java are light-weight processes. Depending on your hardware (CPUs), true parallel execution of code is possible.

This has a lot of implications on programming that you should be aware of. Generally, with java threads you can get into trouble when two threads access the same resource at the same time. In node, you can get into trouble when you block the execution of the main event loop.

See this article for a more in-depth explanation: http://bytearcher.com/articles/parallel-vs-concurrent/